# jquery autocomplete with more items in the same fields

Tags: jquery

I use this function to autocomplete country after enter town

```
 $(function() {
function log( message ) {
  $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
  $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 1 );
}

$( "#town2" ).autocomplete({
  source: "<?php echo $absolute_site . "autocomplete/autocompletetown.php" ?>",
  select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var item = ui.item; // probably modification goes here...
                if(item) {
                    $("#country2").val(item.country);                       
                }

  }
})
    .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" +item.value + "," +item.state + "," + item.country + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

});

GOAL
How can I have the item.value and the item.state in the field #town2, so that after selecting the town in the field #town2 I will have something like

Miami is in Florida (where Miami is item.value and Florida is item.state).
I did search everywhere, but I can find only multiple values (and not multiple items...) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to simply set the value the same way you do for country. Also `return false` to prevent plugin itself setting the value

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
        var item = ui.item; 
        if(item) {
              $("#country2").val(item.country); 
              $(this).val(item.value +' is in ' + item.state);   
              return false;                   
        }    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks , but no luck :( It doesn't work... I did trhy $(this)  and $("town2")

Comment: any errors thrown in console? Does data have those properties?

Comment: the field #country2 works: if I select a town, it autocompletes. This is a piece of the source file `[{"value":"Miami","state":"Fl","country":"US"}.... ` Any idea where an error could hide?

Comment: ahh.. I know. The plugin sets the value also. Use a short `setTimeout()` so plugin finishes setting value first. I was wondering about that earlier that setting different value might be tricky

Comment: Sorry Charlie, you lost me there... could you please show me where to modify the script, I'm really new with javascript. Thanks!

Comment: oooo   try adding `return false` after value gets set...see my update. Will stop plugin from setting value. Demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/KBV4zX3Wn8zzm15NH7Sb?p=preview

Comment: great it works now.... but I don't understand why :( when I read the jquery dociumentation, I often see "setter" and "getter", but I don't 'get' what they exactly do...

Comment: setter means it sets a value to something ...getter means it gets a value

Comment: `$("#country2").val(item.country);` is this the "setter" line you referred before?

Comment: yes..  using function `val()` to be `setter`.... then `var country = $("#country2").val()` ... is using `val()` as getter

Comment: Sorry, very last question, I promise. why return false fixes the problem?

Comment: Thanks! Now I have enough info to dig into!!

Comment: Hi Charlie, I was trying to loop this code. I posted another question, but I had no answers. If you have a minute, could you please get a look at it? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145638/loop-jquery-autocomplete-second-field