# jquery do calculation (in function) when loading page

Tags: jquery

I need to calculate the average of the inputs, sum and print it in the input `#average`.

I am using this (adapted) code from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
       //handler to trigger sum event
       $(".sum").each(function() {
         $(this).keyup(function(){
           calculateSum();
         });
       });
    });

    function calculateSum() {
       var sum = 0;
       //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
       $(".sum").each(function() {
         //add only if the value is number
         if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
           sum += parseFloat(this.value) /7;
         }
       });
       //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
       $("#average").val(sum.toFixed(2));     
    }
</script>
```

**EDITED**:

I have one problem now:

1) When I load my page (and inputs.sum retrieve data from db) the `#average` is blank, up until I don't modify an input.

How should I modify my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to compute the average on document ready and every time a change to any input field happens (Iused input field type number but this snippet works also for input type text):

```js
function calculateAverage() {
  var sum = 0;
  var numOfInputs = $(".sum").length;
  $(".sum").each(function (index, ele) {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $("#average").val((sum / numOfInputs).toFixed(0));
}

$(function () {
  // compute the average at document ready
  calculateAverage();
  
  // compute the average whenever an input field change
  $(".sum").on('input', function() {
    calculateAverage();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#average {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#174C68;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
input {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form>
    Number 1:
    <input type='number' class="sum" value="1"><br>
    Number 2:
    <input type='number' class="sum" value="2"><br>
    Number 3:
    <input type='number' class="sum" value="3"><br>
    Average:
    <input type="number" id="average">
</form>
```

If you have more averages to compute the for loop should be:

```js
function calculateAverage() {
  var sum = 0;
  var numOfInputs = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i<5; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    numOfInputs =  $(".sum" + i).length;
    $(".sum" + i).each(function (index, ele) {
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    $("#average" + i).val((sum / numOfInputs).toFixed(0));
  }
}
$(function () {
  calculateAverage();
  $('[class^="sum"]').on('input', function() {
    calculateAverage();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 15%;
}
input.average {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  color:#174C68;
  width: 10%;
}
input[class^="sum"] {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <label>Number 1:</label>
    <input type='number' class="sum1" value="1">
    <input type='number' class="sum2" value="1">
    <input type='number' class="sum3" value="1">
    <input type='number' class="sum4" value="1"><br>
    <label>Number 2:</label>
    <input type='number' class="sum1" value="2">
    <input type='number' class="sum2" value="2">
    <input type='number' class="sum3" value="2">
    <input type='number' class="sum4" value="2"><br>
    <label>Number 3:</label>
    <input type='number' class="sum1" value="3">
    <input type='number' class="sum2" value="3">
    <input type='number' class="sum3" value="3">
    <input type='number' class="sum4" value="3"><br>
    <label>Average:</label>
    <input type="number" class="average" id="average1">
    <input type="number" class="average" id="average2">
    <input type="number" class="average" id="average3">
    <input type="number" class="average" id="average4">
</form>
```

Instead, if you can organize your input in a table the result will be more simple:

```js
function calculateAverage() {
  var sum = 0;
  var numOfInputs = $('table > tbody > tr').length;
  // clear the averages
  $('table > tfoot > tr > td:gt(0)').each(function(index, ele) {
    $(ele).find('.average').val('0');
  });
  // for each row in the body
  $('table > tbody > tr').each(function(index, ele) {
    // for each column in the current row
    $(ele).find('td:gt(0)').each(function(index, ele) {
      // update the corresponding average computing the sum
      var currVal = parseFloat($(ele).find('.sum').val()) || 0;
      var currAverageObj = $('table > tfoot > tr > td:eq(' + (index + 1) + ') > input');
      currAverageObj.val(parseFloat(currAverageObj.val()) + currVal);
    });
  });
  // adjust the average value dividing by the number of elements
  $('table > tfoot > tr > td:gt(0)').each(function(index, ele) {
    var currentAverageObj = $(ele).find('.average');
    currentAverageObj.val((parseFloat(currentAverageObj.val()) / numOfInputs).toFixed(0));
  });
}
$(function () {
  calculateAverage();
  $('[class^="sum"]').on('input', function() {
    calculateAverage();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.average {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#174C68;
  text-align: right;
  width: 99%;
}
input {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
td {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Value1</th>
                <th>Value2</th>
                <th>Value3</th>
                <th>Value4</th>
                <th>Value5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Elems1</td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="3"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="4"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elems2</td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="3"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="4"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elems3</td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="3"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="4"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elems4</td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="3"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="4"></td>
                <td><input type='text' class="sum" value="5"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Average</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="average"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="average"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="average"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="average"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="average"></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't make it work, should I still use the top part of the script $(document).ready... ? Also my script is in an echo of php. Can I replace 'input' with "input" (double quote)?

Comment: Now I get infinity in my `#average...`

Comment: It works! Thanks! Last question, if my if I want to generate more averages with a php loop .sum$i, I imagine I could do it with $(".sum+i") and $("#average"+i). But where should I put the `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){ code }` in the loop in the script? Thanks again!

Comment: thanks gaemaf very helpful, but the loop in the code snipped doesn't work. If you modify the first value, all the averages, get affected. It's like if the every average gets the value of the previous averages... could you please verify? (It's the snippet with the loop, the second one) Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thanks! I will appreciate!

Comment: @codeispoetry  Sorry for the delay, I updated the second snippet as you asked. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect! Gaemaf, if you have some time, sometimes, and if I'm not asking too much, could you get a look at this other question? It's always about loops in jquery. It's a few days I've asked, but I wasn't lucky with help. Thanks again!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145638/loop-jquery-autocomplete-second-field

Comment: @codeispoetry Give me time. Tomorrow I'll take a look. See soon

Comment: Hi Gaemaf, ho are you? I've to disturb you again... I have some truble with draggable lists in jquery... if you have a chance and it's not too much trouble, could please get a look at this question I've posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36118256/jquery-sortable-with-multiple-lists-and-and-button-to-save-change-conncet-to-my Sorry for disturbing you again! Thanks!